# Cloud Functions - Preventing triggers on certain fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an app that people can request food , then I have orders, each order have an status for that order so I made a function that will send a user notification each time the status of this order changes, the status can be changed by the store which take the order and by the user when the order is done.

But I want to limit the execution of this function to just 2 fields, the userId and the status fields, because now I have onUpdated, this trigger will always launch whenever an update is made to this document.

I'm planning to update other fields than uid and status for this document and I dont want the trigger to relaunch again and send a notification to the user if not needed.

Is there anyway to limit the trigger by just certain fields in the document?

```
exports.onOrderUpdated = functions.firestore
.document('orders/{orderId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

    var db = admin.firestore();

    try{
        const orderDataSnap = change.after.data();
        var userId = orderDataSnap.uid;
        var orderStatus = orderDataSnap.status;
    }catch(error){
        return handleErrorToUser(error);
    }
```

Here I only want to execute this function only when userId and status changes in that document

Is there anyway to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change?authuser=0), there are `before` and `after` [snapshots](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html).

You can call the `data()` method on each of these these and check if the `userId` and `status` are both equal in the before and after copies. If they are, just return out of the function early.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time !

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't any possibility to trigger a Cloud Function only if some specific fields of a document are changed. As explained by samdy1 in his answer you can detect, within the Cloud Function, which field(s) has(ve) changed but for that **the Cloud Function needs to be triggered**.

One solution would be to write a document to another dedicated collection, in parallel to the change.

For example, if you are updating the document with a new `status`, you write a doc to a collection `statusUpdates` with the ID of the parent order document and the status value, and you trigger a Cloud Function based on this document creation.

Of course, it implies a document creation and it has a cost (In addition to the CF triggering). It's up to you to do the math, depending on the frequency of the updates, to calculate if this approach will be cheaper than the approach consisting in triggering the Cloud Function for the order document for nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Renaud, I accepted the first answer per time answered